# jQuery slideToggle "arrow" change for each div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good morning, I have troubles with propper arrow switch for slideToggle. I have 3 of them them but the arrow is changing only for the 1st one - even if I click on different div. Any ideas what I`ve overlooked? Thank you

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8y6xb9n5/)

//jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.flip').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle('fast');
        var src = $('#arrow').attr('src') == "arrow-down.png" ? "arrow-up.png" : "arrow-down.png";
        $('#arrow').attr('src', src);
  });
});
```

//html

```
<div id="container">    
    <div class="flip">One   <img id="arrow" src="arrow-down.png" alt="" /></div>

    <div class="panel"> 
        <p>Foo</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">    
    <div class="flip">Two   <img id="arrow" src="arrow-down.png" alt="" /></div>

    <div class="panel"> 
        <p>Bar</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">    
    <div class="flip">Xxx   <img id="arrow" src="arrow-down.png" alt="" /></div>

    <div class="panel"> 
        <p>Yyy</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pointing to the global `$('#arrow')` instead of the one inside the concerned `.flip`.
I solved this way:

```
$(this).find('#arrow').attr('src', src);
```

I updated your jsFiddle…

### http://jsfiddle.net/8y6xb9n5/1/

…but your code is still a bit messy. You shouldn't declare `id="arrow"` more than once. Use classes instead.
Also, comparing the src with a ternary instruction is a bit heavy-looking. Here also, use classes (`.addClass()`, `.removeClass()`) and `background-image`.

In general, `<img>` is for content (like photos) while css's background is for interface (like icons).

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 img's all with the same id **arrow**, and you're changing **src** for all of them. Use this instead:

```
    var src = $(this).children('#arrow').attr('src') == "http://www.tuneup.cz/fileadmin/images/2014/others/arrow-down.png" ? "http://www.tuneup.cz/fileadmin/images/2014/others/arrow-up.png" : "http://www.tuneup.cz/fileadmin/images/2014/others/arrow-down.png";
    $(this).children('#arrow').attr('src', src);
```

Comment: Also, you should make **arrow** a class, instead of id (since you are using it more than once in your page)

Comment: Thanks is this just "stylistic" problem or does it affect the function itself?

Comment: Yeah, you can say defining it as an id is a stylistic problem.